# How to take screenshots on macOS without having to remember a bunch of key combinations?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

There was a program called Grab.app on earlier versions of macOS that you ran to make screenshots.

Now there are only combinations of keys that take the screenshot. I can't remember these and have to spend some time googling for the combination, which leads me to takes me to lists of they keys including very difficult ones to access

Is there way to get similar behaviour to the  way the Grab.app did this that is as a standard macOS application with its functions provided by menu. (or any other way of getting these functions on a menu e.g. services or menu-bar)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Screenshot.app

The application *Screenshot.app* replaces [*Grab.app*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grab_(software)) in recent macOS versions. You can find *Screenshot* in the *Applications > Utilities* folder.

Once started, the *Screenshot* app presents an overlay with a selection area and a toolbar with buttons to:

- Capture the screen, the current window, or the selected area.
- Record the screen or the selected area as a movie.

There are also options like delaying the capture by 5 or 10 seconds, and where to save the file.

For more info, see [*macOS User Guide*](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/welcome/mac) > [*Take screenshots or screen recordings on Mac*](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/take-a-screenshot-or-screen-recording-mh26782/mac).

---

*Remark:* As it was mentioned in a now deleted comment, the macOS Spotlight search finds Screenshot.app even if the old application “Grab“ is used:

[image]

For those who are interested how this works: The Info.plist file of Screenshot.app has an `MDItemKeywords":"Grab"` entry.

Answer (score 13):

## *Preview* app

Additionally to the answers already provided, the built-in **Preview.app** lets you make screenshots under the "File > Take Screenshot" sub-menu.

[image: screenshot of File > Take Screenshot menu item]

Answer (score 5):

Note that it's also possible to add a shortcut to Screenshot.app directly to the Touch Bar, if you have one.

[image: Touch Bar with Screenshot button]

You can add it from the Keyboard settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome new user. Fantastic answer, great work.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Shottr](https://shottr.cc/) which can be triggered by keyboard shortcuts *and* menulet entries. In addition to plain screenshot functionality, it also allows for some basic markup functionality (arrows, boxes, text).

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative answer, however a quite expensive one: some keyboards made for Mac OS have a dedicated screenshot key. For instance, in this keyboard I'm using (Keychron K3), notice the key to the left of <kbd>del</kbd>:

[image]

One nice thing about that dedicated key is that it can be used with <kbd>Control</kbd> as well: pressing it alone is the equivalent of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, which takes the screenshot. However, I normally prefer <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, which copies the screenshot to the clipboard so I can use it on another application quickly, and that dedicated key also does this copy feature.

Comment: Links/names are welcome if they are required to make the answer useful. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/promotion for details.

Comment: You can use Karabinier-elements to make any spare key do that as well. e.g. num lock - print screen aka f15

Answer (score 0):

My solution might seem clumsy to some people, but it works for me!

I have a hot corner - the lower left one, specifically - set to open Launchpad.
Then, in Launchpad, the application in the bottom left corner of the first page is Screenshot.

Now, I know Cmd+Shift+5 is the keyboard combination to bring up the dialogue box for Screenshot.app, but if I'm using the mouse for a task, it's much quicker to keep my hands on the mouse/trackpad and use my hot corner solution.

I've also suggested my solution to a few people who have trouble remembering key combinations. Whilst none have come back to thank me for the solution, they haven't come back to ask me how to take a screenshot, either. Maybe it works for them, too.